# Nested tables React

Tags: reactjs, uitableview, nested, dialog, material-table

I am using [react material table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling)  to create a table. Inside this I open a  modal dialog and I need to  create another  table inside de dialog.

in my code there is  a layout to my table which contains all I need so I just need to use my template to create the table and I did.

**What happens** : When I run the application my dialog doesn't open and the app crashes out. it doesn't compile my second table.
Sometimes it throws me errors about render and nesting. Once it said something about re-rendering or nesting too much times usetate.

[Here is an example of it](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-material-table-3wpgv?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I see none of your code inside the given example link?

Comment: Hey so sorry. please review it again. I made some change trying to solve the problem however I haven't fixed it

Comment: I still cannot see your `dialog` component, miss?

Comment: I have add it now. I doesn't open though , please forgive my lack of experience.

Comment: Anyways I have another example in here but it doesn't work either https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-framework-e01ix?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I leaved some explanations down below.

Answer (score 0):

### When clicking to `the button` it says: "action.onClick is not a function"

So the first thing you need to check is the declaration or the assignment of that button here:

`onClick: { handleClickOpen }`

Then click to check the `onClick` type it says: `onClick: (event: any, data: RowData | RowData[]) => void;`

**So obviously it doesn't accept an object but a function:**

You then need to change to this to make it works:

`onClick: handleClickOpen`

---

**In your second sourcecode it's failed because you do not return anything from `basicTable.js`**

Try to put something in it like:

```
import React from "react";

export default function BasicTable() {
  return <div>123</div>;
}
```